# ControlLoaded event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I know there is no such event, but is there something similar I can use?

I have ASP.NET usercontrols which are loaded dynamically into a container, which gives a very smooth effect.

The downside of doing this is that I want to run some client-side javascript when a control has finished loading, and I don't know how.

It took me a while to figure out why my jQuery scripts weren't running, then I realised they only ran on `$(document).ready()` and that only occurs when the entire page loads! (Duh!)

Can anyone think of a way of doing this?

Thanks :)

---

Getting more complicated now!

I'm trying to use a DOM Mutation Observer to watch the container so I can run a script when it changes.

But I'm getting an error: `An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.`

The DOM element does exist, but I'm not sure I understand the error correctly.

Here is my observer code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // select the target node
    var target = $('#contentPanel');

    if (typeof (target) != 'undefined') {
        // create an observer instance
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                console.log(mutation.type);
                if (mutation.addedNodes) {
                    alert('New nodes');
                }
                //rememberMe();
            })
        });

        // configuration of the observer:
        var config = { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: true }

        // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
        observer.observe(target, config); // <== error occurs here
    }
});
```

---

The final observer code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // select the target node
    var target = $('#contentPanel');

    if (typeof (target) != 'undefined') {
        // create an observer instance
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            var doRememberMe = false;
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                if (mutation.addedNodes) {
                    doRememberMe = true;
                }
            })
            if (doRememberMe) rememberMe();
        });

        // configuration of the observer:
        var config = { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: true }

        // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
        //observer.observe(target, config);
        observer.observe(document.body, config); // <== apply observer to whole document! (could be done nicer)
    }
});
```

Comment: When would this event fire? What do you mean by "loaded"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: How are you loading the controls?

Comment: Ok. A control is loaded (using the LoadControl method) into an Ajax panel during an ajax postback event. It could be a different control depending on which button caused the postback, etc.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to fire an event when a specific portion of HTML is loaded unless you use JavaScript to call a function when one piece of HTML is loaded onto the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was **eventually** able to get it working using the DOM Mutation code added above.

However the only way it would work was if I applied the listener to the whole document.

For some reason I wasn't able to apply it just to the element that was being modified; perhaps for some reason it was going out of scope, even though I was able to test it existed first! Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Got it, in that case try this at the end of your container (you can define CallLoadedEvent in a separate JS file):

```
<asp:Panel id="Container" runat="server">
   <!-- controls dynamically load here -->
   <script>
      CallLoadedEvent();
   </script>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Thanks will try that on Monday. The other thing I thought about was maybe just embedding a block of script on the control itself, as scripts run when loaded.

Comment: tried it but it didn't work. I think the entire contents of the panel are being replaced when the control is loaded. I also tried embedding the entire script in the html of the control, but this only works when the entire page is reloaded, not when just this control is added. Still looking for a solution...